# Why an array's length property's value changes even when set as read-only in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I tried the following code in chrome's console

```
var a = new Array(1,2,3,4);
a.length
```

This shows length as 4 as expected.
Now I tried setting length property as writable: false

```
Object.defineProperty(a, "length", {writable: false});
a[4] = 5;
a.length
```

This results in 5 even though the property is set to writable:false. How did that happen? Shouldn't it have remained the same as it is set to read-only(writable:false)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `writable` property only limits the use of **assignment operators** to that **property itself**. Also, **the default of `writable` property is already `false`**.

For example:

```
var a = new Array(1,2,3,4);
a.length;    # 4
a.length++;  # a.length is still 4
```

You can see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

If you wish to keep that original value of `a.length`, I think you'd better assign it to another variable:

```
x = [1,2,3,4];   # x.length is 4
y = x.length;    # y is 4
x = [1,2,3,4,5]  # x.length is now 5, but y is still 4
```

Comment: I presume you mean the default value of 'writable' is false for the length property of an array. Also length in your example is 4 and stays 4 not 5.

Answer (score 5):

`Object.defineProperty(a, "length", {writable: false});` only affect the way you assign the value directly to the `.length` property.

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];

Object.defineProperty(a, "length", {writable: false});

a.length = 0;

console.log(a.length); // still be 4
```

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on what actually `length` property returns. See the following example

```
var MyObject = function(){
    var _count = 0;
    this.increment = function(){
        _count++;
    } 
    this.getCount = function(){
        return _count;
    } 
};

var object = new MyObject();

Object.defineProperty(object, "count", {   // new property `count` calls `getCount`
    writeable:false,
    get: function(){
        return this.getCount();  
    }
});


alert(object.count);  // 0
object.count = 90;
object.increment();
alert(object.count);  // 1
object.count = 100;
object.increment();  
alert(object.count); //2
```

Making a property `read-only` means you cannot assign value to it. At the same time it does not change what the property returns when it is read. It depends on the internal definition of that property.